# Синоним к слову МОТАТЬСЯ

Tags: синонимы

Надо было подобрать синоним к слову МОТАТЬСЯ в предложении: "Он привык МОТАТЬСЯ по прибрежной тропинке босиком". Я написала ПРОГУЛИВАТЬСЯ и это засчитали за ошибку. Я не права?

Answer (score 6):

Просторечное слово "мотаться" включает в свое значение элемент суетливости, быстроты, подвижности. А прогуливаться - это гулять не спеша, медленно. Чтобы понять значение слова и подобрать синоним, часто нужно прочесть не одно предложение, а несколько. Возможно, здесь подошло бы слово "бегать".

Answer (score 4):

Согласна с Ларf. "Прогуливался" точно не подойдет. Могу предложить еще "шастал", "сновал", "носился".

Comment: Да, Вы правы, это все синонимы. Но похоже, это задание В1 ГИА 9 класс. Нужно подобрать к слову разговорного стиля нейтральный синоним. Поэтому "шастал" вряд ли подойдет.

Comment: Да, тогда не подойдет.

Answer (score 3):

Из текста неясна цель, а также темп передвижения, а от этого зависит выбор синонима. Если он ходит куда-то постоянно, то возможен синоним "таскаться".

ПРЕДЛАГАЕТСЯ ЕЩЕ ОДИН ОТВЕТ
Предложение составлено неудачно, пусть автор отзовется (смайлик).

Вот ситуации, кагда мы используем слово "мотаться". Все они имеют обобщенное значение "постоянно находиться в движении (часто утомительном) по различным текущим делам"
Мотаться с утра до ночи по неотложным делам. Мотаться без дела по целым дням. … Мотаться по свету.Признаюсь, не хочется вечно мотаться по арендам. В субботу мотались по делам, Сегодня "мотаясь" по делам, нашла сотовый телефон.
Я мотаюсь, как клубок, по городам Дорогого мне Советского Союза: То Ташкент, то Магадан, Но везде - и тут и там - Я живу чуть лучше Робинзона Крузо

Comment: София: 
> Из текста неясна цель, а также темп
> передвижения, а от этого зависит выбор
> синонима. Если он ходит куда-то
> постоянно, то возможен синоним "таскаться".

По-моему, семантический акцент в предложении выражен связкой "привык <...> босиком". А потому цель и темп передвижения здесь вторичны, и в качестве нейтрального синонима "мотаться" подойдёт упомянутый глагол "бегать".

Answer (score 2):

По Ожегову мотаться - Проводить время в хлопотливых, утомительных занятиях, ходьбе (прост.). Целый день м. по городу.Значит, нейтральный синоним БРОДИТЬ или ходить.

Comment: Задание мне знакомо,и ключи к нему есть, там ответ "ходить,бродить" - любое из них будет правильно, но не прогуливаться, там значение "гулять, отдыхая", а здесь ходить,утомляясь(мотаться-замотанный, уставший). Бродить - тоже оттенок усталости, но ходить - общий смысл,видимо, самое подходящее.

Answer (score 2):

З. Е. Александрова. Словарь синонимов русского языка. Издание 5-е, стереотипное. Москва. "Русский язык". 1986.   ...ХОДИТЬ/без цели, без дела: бродить, шататься, болтаться, шляться, слоняться, трепаться, мотаться, шлендать, шастать (прост.)... Одного данного предложения недостаточно для выбора близкого по смыслу синонима слову "мотаться". К слову "босиком" больше подходит глагол "бегать", а не "ходить". Поэтому "мотаться" в данном случае означает - неоднократно торопливо проходить туда-сюда (что-то среднее между "бегать" и "ходить"), а соответствия этой подборке слов одного синонима, кажется, нет

Comment: Босиком  можно  как  и  ходить,  так  и  бегать.  Я  бы  выбрал  синонимом  "шататься",  а  если  нужно  нейтральное - то  "ходить".

Answer (score 2):

Сдается мне тут как раз не синоним надо подбирать, а именно слово, более соответствующее по смыслу, а не просто совпадающее по значению.

Мотаться - не то слово. 
А вот что имел в виду автор этого теста - непонятно. То ли то, что нет движения туда-сюда, то ли быстрый темп, предполагаемый глаголом "мотаться". В зависимости от этого надо и нужное слово подбирать. Единого варианта нет. Контекст нужен, а в тесте его понятно, нет.

Разве действительно "прогуливаться" или "прохаживаться". Я крепко сомневаюсь, что кто-то по прибрежной тропе ***босиком*** именно ***бегает***. Бегают по прибрежному песку - хорошее, вроде, физическое упражнение, но по тропинке...

Comment: Мы по тропинке очень даже бегаем! Тропинка ведь не только в лесу.

Comment: Я вам завидую. )))
Я когда-то тоже мог бегать по тропинкам... Но не босиком же? 
А причем тут лес?

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему, не надо мудрствовать, все понятно из одного предложения."Надюшка"(2 коммент)дала самый точный ответ.

Comment: Нет,  не  самый  точный !  К  слову  "мотаться"  в  этом  контексте  очень  точных  синонимов  нет.